# Can Storybook 6.2 work with Angular 11 in an ASP.NET Core 5 Solution?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, storybook

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 Solution that has a project within it containing an Angular 11 application. My goal is to install and use Storybook for maintaining my components. However, when I do, the Storybook UI can't find my templates and attempts to get them through HTTP GET which results in a 404 Not Found.

If I put all the template code directly into the component's `template` metadata then Storybook works properly.  It is only when I reference the HTML in a file using the `templateUrl` metadata that I get the error. Putting all the HTML into each component is, of course, impractical.

Things I've tried:

1. I created a new, solo Angular application using the Angular CLI. Then, I installed Storybook. Everything works as expected and no HTTP calls are being used to get the template files.
2. Using the newly created, solo Angular application, I compared its Storybook **installation** console output to that of the .NET output.  I didn't see anything obvious.
3. Using the newly created, solo Angular application, I compared its Storybook **run** console output to that of the .NET output.  I didn't see anything obvious.
4. Using the newly created, solo Angular application, I compared Storybook's various **configuration files** with those found in the .NET application.  I didn't see anything obvious.

At this point, I'm inclined to say that the issue lies somewhere in the .NET/Angular combo or maybe just in the .NET solution itself although I can't be completely sure.

---

This is a screenshot of the strange GET:

[image: Template GET Header]

This is a screenshot of the errors in the console:

[image: Console Errors]